# How to get the value of one specific JSON key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table called images and a field called dataResponse.

In the field dataResponse I have this json:

```
{
    "test": {
        "test1": 3,
        "test2": 5,
        "test3": 7
    },
}
```

How can I select the value of 'test1'?

Comment: What's the data format of the `dataResponse` column?

Comment: Data type is text @Martin

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.7 anyway, it's solved

Answer (score 3):

Use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract).
`SELECT dataResponse->"$.test.test1"`

Comment: SELECT dataResponse->"$.test.test1" works on 5.7, thanks!